# Cannot invoke "+=" with an argument list of type (Int, @value Int)

Tags: swift, variable-assignment, increment

I have a class `Transaction` which has a **var amount** of type `Int`.
I want to access it from another class, where I have an `array of Transactions` and sum all of their amounts.

So I have this piece of code

```
func computeTotal()-> Int{
    let total = 0
    for transaction in transactions{
        //get the amounts of each and sum all of them up
        total += transaction.amount
    }
    return total
}
```

But it gives me an error

**Cannot invoke "+=" with an argument list of type (Int, @value Int)**

What can cause that? I know that in Swift both operands must be the same type, but they are both of type Int in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let` creates an immutable value. You need to use `var`, like:

```
func computeTotal()-> Int{
    var total = 0
    for transaction in transactions{
        //get the amounts of each and sum all of them up
        total += transaction.amount
    }
    return total
}
```